# PHPStorm: Syntax Highlighting for PHP code inside XML tags

Tags: syntax-highlighting, phpstorm

Is there any way to make PHPStorm apply syntax highlighting to PHP code inside a tag in an XML file?

I'm working on an OpenCart project and I'm using [Vqmod](https://code.google.com/p/vqmod/), which requires that I write PHP code in an XML file. For example:

```
<operation>
    <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
        <?php echo "123"; ?>
    ]]></search>

    <add><![CDATA[
        <?php echo "xyz"; ?>
    ]]></add>

</operation>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1)** `Settings | File Types` -- assign `*.xml` (or whatever file name pattern you think is more appropriate) to `PHP files` entry (you may need to remove it from "XML files" first).

This will tell PhpStorm to **treat such files as PHP** (it's the only way to have PHP support).

The possible negative side -- it's an IDE-wide setting and will affect ALL such files in ALL projects. Therefore -- if you can name such files in some unique way (e.g. double extension: `*.php.xml` or `*.xml.php`; unique extension: `*.pxml`; unique file name ending: `*layout.xml`) then do it.

**2)** `Settings | Template Data Languages` -- find such files (or whole folder) and assign **XML** in 2nd column.

This will tell PhpStorm to treat such files as "PHP with XML" instead of default "PHP with HTML".

---

**Official manual:** http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Syntax+highlighting+of+PHP+inside+JavaScript+%28and+other+languages%29

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am marking it as accepted because it answers my original question. Unfortunatelly, the PHP code is inside CDATA tags and it seems PHPStorm doesn't want to apply syntax highlighting inside those. Any idea for that?

Comment: Yes, I reset the settings and now it shows up for me as well. Must be something in the way I configured the editor. I'll try to find out what it is. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LazyOne Do you know if it is possible for step 2 to use file extension rather than file path ?

Comment: @syl.fabre Not possible -- Settings screen allows to set it up based on path only (Unless you will code some plugin that would somehow do such job for you dynamically). You can file **Feature Request** to the [Issue Tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) though -- maybe they will implement this one day...

Comment: @LazyOne I hoped you add an alternative way to achieve this! Thanks for your answer

Comment: @syl.fabre You should ask devs not me.

Comment: Can someone enlighten me as to where "Settings" is? The closest thing I can find is "Preferences", but even then I don't think I'm able to find the same controls from that screen...

Comment: @AndyCorman `Settings` is for Windows/Linux. On Mac it uses standard `Preferences` name which is located at the same place where any other Mac program has it. Then, in current versions of IDE -- `Preferences | Editor | File Types` and `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Template Data Languages` **P.S.** Settings/Preferences screen has quick search facility -- if you would use it you would find those settings very quickly.